# How can i remove duplicate image for same product

Tags: magento-1.9, image

How can i remove duplicate image for same product. Actually product contains 4 images, and also default image (image coming soon). how to remove that.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The default image shows up if the actual image file is missing. So your situation here is, that the two "image coming soon" images are actually two different images but the files are missing.

The obvious solution is to go to the product management and remove the missing images.

[image]

Comment: no, i set all images, but i don't know, why Image Coming Soon Image displayed.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/sSjIhUa.png

Comment: what about rows 2,4,5 and 7?

Comment: sorry, i couldn't get you.

Comment: I added an image, hope that helps.

Comment: ok, but i need to remove 100 products of images,  how can i remove using bulk edit

Comment: 100 products has same problem, how can i remove bulk edit

Comment: Write a script that goes through all images and check if the file exists. Here is an example: https://gist.github.com/peterjaap/5547654

Comment: how can i use this

Comment: from the command line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41382/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-fschmengler).

Comment: could you pls guide me how can i run this,